# Problem with Android 12 and the HapticGenerator API: Audio track randomly start to play at maximum volume. (Even when sound is muted)

Tags: android, haptic-feedback

Using a Pixel 4 running Android 12 I try to use the new HapticGenerator API (API level >= 31) to generate haptic feedback from an audio track.

However, I observe a random problem where the audio track is played during the first milliseconds at maximum volume. (Even if the volume of the phone is fully muted).

I've made a sample [application](https://github.com/mbaril/AndroidHapticGenerator) that reproduce the problem that I'm facing.

Relevant part of the code that setup the MediaPlayer and the HapticGenerator:

```
    private MediaPlayer player = null;
    private HapticGenerator hapticGenerator = null;
    
    private void releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            player.release();
        }
        if (hapticGenerator != null) {
            hapticGenerator.release();
        }
    }

    private void play() {
        button.setEnabled(false);
        releasePlayer();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sniper_rifle);
        if (HapticGenerator.isAvailable()) {
            hapticGenerator = HapticGenerator.create(player.getAudioSessionId());
            hapticGenerator.setEnabled(true);
        }
        player.setOnCompletionListener(mp -> button.setEnabled(true));
        player.start();
    }
```

As you can see the code is quite simple but randomly the audio track start at full volume during couple of milliseconds.

- Anyone already experienced this problem?
- Any workaround or suggestion?
- If you have another phone model that support the HapticGenerator API
  do you observe the same problem? I'm wondering if the problem is
  specific to the pixel 4 implementation.

Comment: Reported as a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242017146)